# Selenium python chromedriver click to close cookie popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using this website: https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/

I have added various arguments and experimental options to disable popups but the pop-up you will see keeps coming up.

I am trying to close it by clicking the big green Accept & Close button but the error says that no such element exists

code:

```
url='https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/'
logger.info('loading:',url)
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
options.experimental_options["prefs"]=chrome_prefs
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",['disable-popup-blocking'])
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"popups":1}
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\\foo',options=options)
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept & Close']").click()
```

[image: html doc]

tree structure:

```
<div class="message-component message-row" style="padding: 3px 5px; 
margin: 5px 10px; border-width: 0px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border- 
radius: 0px; border-style: solid; width: calc(100% - 30px); height: 
auto; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; flex-direction: 
column;"><button title="Accept &amp; Close" class="message-component 
message-button no-children focusable primary accept customizable 
sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 10px 0px; margin: 0px 5px; border- 
width: 0px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 5px; border- 
style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; color: rgb(255, 255, 
255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(60% - 
10px); background: rgb(24, 144, 255);">Accept &amp; Close</button></div>

    <button title="Accept &amp; Close" class="message-component message- 
    button no-children focusable primary accept customizable 
    sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 10px 0px; margin: 0px 5px; border- 
    width: 0px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 5px; border- 
    style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; color: rgb(255, 255, 
    255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(60% - 
    10px); background: rgb(24, 144, 255);">Accept &amp; Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to the URL on your question and no pop-up came up. But I have also had your problem. In my case putting,

```
import time
time.sleep(4) #change the seconds till it works for you
```

before `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept & Close']").click()` Worked. The second count will need a little tuning.

Comment: i dont think its a wait issue, i can see the popup coming but when i run the code i get this error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@title='Accept & Close']"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

Answer (score 0):

Either apply `Implicit wait`:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
```

Or Apply `Explicit wait` like below and try.

```
driver.get("https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/")
time.sleep(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Accept & Close']")))

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept & Close']")
# Trial 1
button.click()

# Trial 2
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(button).click().perform()

# Trial 3
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click",button)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: i dont think it's a wait time as I can see it popping up when i run the script. The wait.until returns a TimeoutException error

Comment: @matthewr - I dont see the pop-up now. Can you share the HTML DOM in the question

Comment: added tree structure

Comment: @matthewr - Try with these xpath `//button[contains(text(),'Close')]` or   `//button[ends-with(text(),'Close')]`

Comment: still says NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Close')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the [Link](https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/). Please share the screen shot of the page with pop-up and HTML DOM highlighting the `Accept and close` button.

Comment: yup that is the correct link, picture added

Comment: @matthewr - I am not able to see any screen shot added!

Comment: @matthewr - Got [https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE2uw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE2uw.png) but need to see the HTML DOM of that Element.

Comment: added a picture in my post of the element

Comment: @matthewr - I have updated my answer. Try all the Trials and check whether you are able to click on that button. And do apply `time.sleep(10)`